# regular expression to capture between underscores

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression to describe the part of a file name between the first and last underscore. An underscore may also occur in the middle of the string. I ended up getting what I need with JavaScript, but would have preferred a pure regular expression.

```
Sample file name                                 Desired Result
===============================================  =============================
12345_something goes here_54321                  something goes here
23456_sometimes_an_underscore there_endGoesHere  sometimes_an_underscore there
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can solve this if no other underscores are used, but am stuck when there are embedded underscores.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure regular expression", as opposed to using regular expression with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will satisfy your needs ;-)

```
^(?:[^_]*_)?(.*?)(?:_[^_]*)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8h2hqOH_ZIZW_MQO)

Comment: `^[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*$` should suffice.  The optional groups and the non-greedy `.*?` serve no purpose other than to slow down the match.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would define a regular expression that consists of 3 groups. The first group would be any number if non underscore characters terminated by an underscore. The second would be any number of any characters and the last would be an underscore followed any any number  of non underscore characters followed by an end of line. You'd then use only the second group.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without regax, like this-

```
$array = explode(" ", $your_string);
```

$array[0] will have the first string & $array[1] will be the second string